# What will be the mysql regex query for this

Tags: mysql, regex

I am not much comfortable with the regex neither in the language side nor in the mysql.

Could you please help me to write a query?

I have a DB table, one column is having data of three kinds the Stock Number, Name and Price. What I am interested in is Stock Number. I did not created this DB design, so bear with me.

The data is in this format:

`[#3346] - $3,500.00, some name`

I have to fetch the records from this table which match the given Stock Number ie `3346`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name REGEXP ?
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
WHERE col_name REGEXP '^\\[#3346\\]'
```

Taking it in parts:

- `^` indicates the start of the string
- `\[` is a literal `[` character (but within a string the `\` itself needs escaping with another `\`)
- `#3346` is the literal string `#3346`
- `\]` is a literal `]` character (but within a string the `\` itself needs escaping with another `\`)

Therefore the above expression matches any string which starts with the literal `[#3346]`.  As it happens, for this purpose you don't even need to use regular expressions as a [simple pattern match](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) would do the trick:

```
WHERE col_name LIKE '[#3346]%'
```

*However*, even though you didn't create the database, I'd strongly advise you to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data structure by splitting `col_name` into three columns.